# Añadir imagenes en lista despegable en HTML

Tags: html, css

estoy haciendo un formulario a través del cual me permita seleccionando una provincia y pulsando un botón me aparezca una imagen determinada. No sé muy bien como hacer el tema de lograr que al seleccionar en la lista despegable y pulsar el botón me aparezca la imagen. Agradezco alguna ayuda.

El código de la lista despegable es este:

```
<label for=”provincia” id=”provincia”>
   <select name=”provincia”>
       <option value=”av”>Selecciona</option>
       <option value=”av”>JAÉN</option>
       <option value=”bu”>CÓRDOBA</option>
       <option value=”l”>SEVILLA</option>
       <option value=”p”>HUELVA</option>
       <option value=”sg”>CÁDIZ</option>
       <option value=”so”>MALAGA</option>
       <option value=”sa”>GRANADA ALMERÍA</option>
       <option value=”va”>ALMERÍA</option>
 </label><br> 
   </select>
    <br><br><br>
   <input type="button" value="Vamos a visitar">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es agregar una función que cargue el valor que tienes seleccionado, y agregue un elemento `img`. Ese elemento tiene un atributo `src` que es la dirección de donde esta la imagen que quieres poner. 
En el código q te muestro, toma las imágenes desde la carpeta img y esta en la misma altura que el index.html. Ademas esas imágenes se llaman de la misma manera q tiene el **value** de cada **option**.

```js
function getImgProvincia() {
    var valorProvincia = document.getElementById('selectProvincia').value;
    document.getElementById('imgContenedor').innerHTML = '<img src="imgs/'+valorProvincia+'.png">';
  }
```

```css
#imgContenedor{
    width: 100%
}
#imgContenedor img{
  display: block;
  margin: auto !important
}
```

```html
<label for=”provincia” id=”provincia”>
  <select name=”provincia” id="selectProvincia">
    <option value=”av”>Selecciona</option>
    <option value=”av”>JAÉN</option>
    <option value=”bu”>CÓRDOBA</option>
    <option value=”l”>SEVILLA</option>
    <option value=”p”>HUELVA</option>
    <option value=”sg”>CÁDIZ</option>
    <option value=”so”>MALAGA</option>
    <option value=”sa”>GRANADA ALMERÍA</option>
    <option value=”va”>ALMERÍA</option>
</label><br>
</select>
<br><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="getImgProvincia();" value="Vamos a visitar">
<div id="imgContenedor"></div>
```

Al final esa imagen seleccionada se muestra en una region abajo.

Esto es un **ejemplo**, por lo que no se van a mostrar la imágenes. Para eso, tiene q existir la carpeta img y dentro las imágenes, con su nombre correspondiente.

Comment: No se muestra la imagen. ¿ Se debe al formato o hace falta sobredimensionarla en la hoja de estilo?

Comment: en el ejemplo q te mostre yo, no se muestra la imagen porque no existe una carpeta img ni hay imagenes. Solo es el ejemplo. Si no te andan en tu programa, puede ser por varias razones, una puede ser, por que no tenes bien la ruta de la carpeta img (o no la creaste, directamente), o porque las imagenes no tienen el mismo nombre.

Comment: Vale y para que aparezca centrada cuando se ejecute. ¿ Tendría que controlarlo con imgContenedor dentro la hoja de estilos, no?

Comment: si, eso ya es en la hoja de estilos. Puedes ponerle `margin: auto; display:block` a la imagen. Eso te la va a centrar **dentro del div** que la contiene. Tambien puedes centrar el div con lo mismo, o darle un `width:100%` para que tome todo el ancho de lo q lo contenga. Si sigues con dudas, sobre tu pregunta, migramos esta conversación a un chat aparte y me las comentas.

Comment: la duda que tengo es esa porque la imagen al ejecutar se me queda fija a la derecha, descuadrada. Y tampoco consigo centrarla con lo que me has dicho

Comment: Puedes ponerlo de la siguiente manera `#imgContenedor{
    width: 100%
  }
  #imgContenedor img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto !important
  }` . Edito mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Hola Rafael lo tendrias que hacer con javascript, yo aca uso jquery.
Se hace de la siguiente forma, en una carpeta guardas las fotos con numeros de cada provincia, en el select en el VALUE pones el numero de cada foto que aplica a cada una de las provincias.

Carpeta de fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego con un Script lo que haces es que cuando le des CLICK al boton capture el value del option que seleccionaste en el select.
Ese value se pasa a esta parte del codigo que lo que hace guardar ese value en una variable para que la uses dsp.

```
var selected = $('#provincia option:selected').val();
```

Y dsp lo guardas en selectes y lo mandas a esta parte donde lo metes en el src de la img y esa imagen es la que va y busca en la carpeta de fotos:

```
$('#fotos').html('<img src="fotos/'+selected+'.jpg">');
```

Acá va el código:

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<label for="provincia" id="provincia">

   <select name="provincia" id="provincia">
   <option value="0">Selecciona</option>
   <option value="1">JAÉN</option>
   <option value="2">CÓRDOBA</option>
   <option value="3">SEVILLA</option>
   <option value="4">HUELVA</option>
   <option value="5">CÁDIZ</option>
   <option value="6">MALAGA</option>
   <option value="7">GRANADA ALMERÍA</option>
   <option value="8">ALMERÍA</option>
 </label><br> 
   </select>

<br><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Vamos a visitar" onClick="verFoto()">

<div id="texto"></div>
<div id="fotos"></div>

<script>

  function verFoto(){
var selected = $('#provincia option:selected').val();
$('#texto').html('Aca iria la foto N°' + selected)
$('#fotos').html('<img src="fotos/'+selected+'.jpg">');
  }
</script>
```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]